# React TS - Passing types to Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

So I currently have a Navigation component that will toggle the background color for the component when it's clicked. My `open` prop gives me the following error:

```
var open: any
Binding element 'open' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Even though I pass my interface to the styled component:

```
const StyledBurgerIcon = styled.div<INavigation>`
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: ${({ open }) => (open ? "red" : "green")};
`;
```

Interface passed:

```
interface INavigation {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: (open: boolean) => void;
}
```

**I don't get this errior on CodeSandBox but it shows this error in VSCode:**

```
const BurgerIcon: StyledComponent<"div", any, INavigation, never>
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | "className" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & INavigation, "key" | ... 255 more ... | "setOpen"> & Partial<...>, "key" | ... 255 more ... | "setOpen"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Property 'setOpen' is missing in type '{ open: boolean; onClick: () => void; }' but required in type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | "className" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & INavigation, "key" | ... 255 more ... | "setOpen"> & Partial<...>, "key" | ... 255 more ... | "setOpen">'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, INavigation, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, INavigation, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
    Property 'setOpen' is missing in type '{ open: boolean; onClick: () => void; }' but required in type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | "className" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & INavigation, "key" | ... 255 more ... | "setOpen"> & Partial<...>, "key" | ... 255 more ... | "setOpen">'.ts(2769)
Navigation.tsx(6, 3): 'setOpen' is declared here.
Navigation.tsx(6, 3): 'setOpen' is declared here.
```

---

**Full code for my Navigation component:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface INavigation {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: (open: boolean) => void;
}

const Navigation: React.FC<INavigation> = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <StyledNav>
      <StyledBurgerIcon open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} />
    </StyledNav>
  );
};

export default Navigation;

const StyledNav = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
const StyledBurgerIcon = styled.div<INavigation>`
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: ${({ open }: {open: boolean}) => (open ? "red" : "green")};
`;
```

Here's a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-rgb-0xu3n)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I believe one of your errors to be using `*` as a declaration for react, unless this is a javascript way of declaring a namespace.

Comment: Also please post your full code.

Comment: Full code is provided in the SandBox. :)

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it is typical practice on SO to post the code instead of a link. Not sure it is absolutely required however, so i'll leave it for a moderator to do something about if they see fit.

Comment: Odd. I'll keep debugging. I'll let you know if I can come up with anything.

Comment: I'm also getting the error that the module `styled-components` cannot be found.

Comment: I get that too, not sure why that is erroring because it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same interface for the `Navigation` component and the `StyledBurgerIcon`.

```
interface INavigation {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: (open: boolean) => void;
}
```

This interface declares a required property `setOpen` which is not necessary in your `StyledBurgerIcon`

You should create a separate interface for the `StylesBurgerIcon` which contains only the `open` property like this:

```
interface IBurgerIconProps {
  open: boolean;
}
```

Then your styled component can use this new interface

```
const StyledBurgerIcon = styled.div<IBurgerIconProps>`
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: ${({ open }: {open: boolean}) => (open ? "green" : "red")};
`;
```

Comment: Which is what I said in my answer, except instead of `boolean` it was `any`.

Comment: But yours is much better formatted. An upvote from me.

Comment: Is a `boolean` required instead of `any`?

Comment: @Death Waltz, I only want the type to be true or false for this, `any` would work too but I want to be more specific.

Comment: Oh, well then bravo @Jackson, I'd like to think I was close.

Comment: @DeathWaltz it is better to specify the types if you know what they are. If you use `any` for all your types then what is the point of using typescript :p